# Convert vector mask to shape layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Photoshop document with many raster layers with Vector Masks applied. I would like to convert these to actual Shape layers.

Is there a better (easier) way to do this than:

1. Select the vector mask in the Layers palette.
2. Use the Direct Selection tool (A) to select the path.
3. Copy.
4. Create a new shape layer (e.g. drag a rectangle (U))
5. Paste the vector path into the shape layer.
6. Use Direct Selection tool to select and delete the original shape path.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: 
click the vector mask to activate it, instead of that layer;
"p" for pen tool, look at the above pen tool toolbar, at the very left make sure "path" mode is selected, then just click "shape" button in the middle of pen tool toolbar.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Maybe some day I'll remember all of these unintuitive methods instead of always having to Google them... 